# Regarding proof of Hermite polynomials, identifying coefficients in two series.

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, proof-explanation, hermite-polynomials

I have a question regarding a proof. The proof uses some results I first present:

[image]

My question is regarding the proof in the last point which is here:

[image]

But how does the last sentence follow, is it easy? How can we just pair up coefficients, what makes them vanish when $k \ne l$. And why must a coefficient with a given k on the l.h.s. correspond to the same k on the r.h.s?

Comment: Power series are unique.

Comment: The first sum runs over general exponents $(k, l)$ of $s$ and $t$ respectively. The second sum runs over exponents of the form $(k,k)$ only. This is why the coefficients vanish for $k \neq l$